# I'm trying to write a code that will find if a matrix is a magic matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix

This is the code that I have so far but it won't return anything and I don't understand why. Thanks for any help

```
is_magic <- function(test){
    test <- matrix(test)
    test_dim <- dim(test)
    if (test_dim[1] == test_dim[2]){
        test_diag <- diag(test)
        diag_sum <- sum(test_diag)
        row_sum <- rowsum(test, nrow(test))
        col_sum <- colsum(test, ncol(test))
        if ((row_sum == col_sum) && (col_sum == diag_sum)){
               return (True)
        } else {
            return (False)

    } 
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square),

> a magic square is a n × n square grid (where n is the number of
>   cells on each side) filled with distinct positive integers in the
>   range  1,2,...,n^2 such that each cell contains a different integer
>   and the sum of the integers in each row, column and diagonal is equal.

There are still a few flaws in your code. I suggest passing a matrix to your function instead of using `matrix` inside of it, and using `rowSums`/`colSums`. In addition, R is case sensitive and boolean values are `TRUE`/`FALSE`, not `True`/`False`.

So maybe try

```
is_magic <- function(test) {
  if (ncol(test) == nrow(test)) { 
    if (length(unique(test))==length(test) && all(test>0)) {
      diag_sum <- sum(diag(test))
      antidiag_sum <- sum(diag(test[,ncol(test):1]))
      row_sum <- rowSums(test)
      col_sum <- colSums(test)
      if (all(row_sum == col_sum) && col_sum[1] == diag_sum && diag_sum == antidiag_sum){
        return (TRUE)
      }
    }
  }
  return(FALSE)
}
is_magic(m<-matrix(c(2,9,4,7,5,3,6,1,8), 3))
# [1] TRUE
is_magic(matrix(c(1,9,4,7,5,3,6,1,8), 3))
# [1] FALSE
```

Comment: do you also need to check the "other" diagonal (right to left, top to bottom)?

Answer (score 0):

Index in R starts at 1:

Replace

```
test_dim[0] == test_dim[1]
```

by

```
test_dim[1] == test_dim[2]
```

Also replace
`nrow[test]` and `ncol[test]` by `nrow(test)`and `ncol(test)`

Comment: thanks, I made those adjustments but it still doesn't return anything.

Comment: @user4343563 note that if  if (test_dim[1] == test_dim[2]) is false, you are not returning anything. add another return(FALSE) when this if is not TRUE

Comment: I had originally had another else statement at the end but then I kept getting an error for an unexpected else